# SourceTree: updating develop and master when both are way behind active branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I find myself in the middle of a project that has tried to use the **git-flow** approach for maintaining code.

- https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/01/smart-branching-with-sourcetree-and-git-flow/
- http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Because the git-flow strategies were not closely followed at the start of the project, the `develop` branch is months behind the latest `feature` branch, and the `master` branch is even further behind the `develop` branch. The `feature-` branches were being used as the branches for code deployment.

The question now is: using SourceTree, what is the best way to update the `develop` and the `master` branches, so that they are essentially exactly the same as the latest `feature` branch that was used for deployment? I don't see anything in `develop` or `master` being useful, since they are out of date and there have been so many changes, so it seems like they both need to be completely over-written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need the changes from `master` or `develop`, the easiest solution would be to do a hard reset on those branches.

1. Switch to `master` by double-clicking it in the left pane.
2. Find the latest commit that has been deployed to production in the Log/History view.
3. Right-click that commit and click `Reset current branch to this commit`.
4. In the confirmation dialog, switch the `Using mode` dropdown to `Hard - discard all working copy changes`, then click OK.

And repeat the process for `develop`.

---

The alternative would be to delete the branches and re-create them.

1. Right click the `master` branch in the left pane.
2. Click `Delete master`.
3. At the confirmation dialog, if the branch has unmerged changes, check the `Force delete` box, then click OK.

Repeat the process for `develop`.

Then, take whatever `feature-*` branch was being used for production deployments, and rename it to `master`:

1. Right click on the relevant `feature-*` branch.
2. Click `Rename feature-*...`.
3. Enter `master` and click OK.

If you have another `feature-*` branch that was being used for development, do the same to rename it to `develop`.

The main difference here is that you will no longer have the `feature-*` branches, which may or may not be what you need.

### Effect on History

Suppose your history looked something like this:

```
... A--B [master]
   /
  *--*--*--C--D [develop]
         \
          *--* ... *--*--* [feature-1] (should be develop)
                  \
                   *--*--* [feature-2] (should be master)
```

After following the above instructions, your history will look like this:

```
... A--B
   /
  *--*--*--C--D
         \
          *--* ... *--*--* [develop, feature-1]
                  \
                   *--*--* [master, feature-2]
```

(Where `feature-1` and `feature-2` may not exist anymore depending on which solution you chose.)

When you move or delete a branch, the commits aren't deleted right away. So commits `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` still exist, you just don't have an easy way to get to them. After a while these commits will be garbage-collected by Git, so be sure to add a branch or tag there if you want to keep them.

Comment: So the hard reset option amounts to a "wipe-out" of the old code in `master`?

Comment: @mg1075 Yes, mostly. Updated my answer to clarify.